# Error 1962 - No Operating System Found

Tags: hard-drive-recovery

Last night, my computer was ok . But when i turned it on in morning , the message says , Error 1962 - No Operating System Found Press F1 to repeat boot sequence. I started the bios and tried looking if the hard drive is detected, but I found the hard drive was not detected. What will I do using programs only?

Comment: Check the hard drive data cable, sometimes they just go bad.

Comment: The computer looks for an operating system.  However, you've probably also lost all of your programs, and all the rest of your data.  Fortunately, "lost" may be a temporary thing; you just need to get that hard drive working again.  See Journeyman Geek's answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I recover lost/inacessible data from my storage device?](http://superuser.com/questions/241817/how-do-i-recover-lost-inacessible-data-from-my-storage-device)

Answer (score 1):

If your hard drive isn't detected in the bios, chances are its dead. No software can recover a drive *it cannot see*. Sudden death happens sometimes and something like this could be indicative of a firmware or hardware error. There's very little that can be done unless you've got access to professional recovery tools (and do things like swapping out controller boards and other fancy stuff,

Hardware dies. Sometimes the best course of action is to restore from your backups and move on.